# Groovy Turkish tax number verification

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I need to calculate Turkish Tax number via Groovy.. Basically it's 10 digit number..

Here is the math behind it..

---

First 9 digit number (d), last 10 digit control ( c )value

Tr tax number = d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 c1

So  d1..d9  >> d[i]

p[i] = (d[i] + 10 — i) mod 10

p[i] = 9 => q[i] = 9

p[i] != 9 => q[i] = (p[i] * 2^(10 — i)) mod 9

c1 = (10 — (Σ q[i] mod 10)) mod 10

Let’s say tax number : 018273645x

p[1] = ( d[1] + 10–1 ) mod 10 = (0 + 10–1) mod 10 = 9

p[2] = ( d[2] + 10–2) mod 10 = (1 + 10–2) mod 10 = 9

p[3] = ( d[3] + 10–3 ) mod 10 = (8 + 10–3) mod 10 = 5

p[4] = ( d[4] + 10–4 ) mod 10 = (2 + 10–4) mod 10 = 8

p[5] = ( d[5] + 10–5 ) mod 10 = (7 + 10–5) mod 10 = 2

p[6] = ( d[6] + 10–6 ) mod 10 = (3 + 10–6) mod 10 = 7

p[7] = ( d[7] + 10–7 ) mod 10 = (6 + 10–7) mod 10 = 9

p[8] = ( d[8] + 10–8 ) mod 10 = (4 + 10–8) mod 10 = 6

p[9] = ( d[9] + 10–9 ) mod 10 = (5 + 10–9) mod 10 = 6

q[1] = 9

q[2] = 9

q[3] = (p[3] * 2^(10–3)) mod 9 = (5 * 2⁷) mod 9 = 1

q[4] = (p[4] * 2^(10–4)) mod 9 = (8 * 2⁶) mod 9 = 8

q[5] = (p[5] * 2^(10–5)) mod 9 = (2 * 2⁵) mod 9 = 1

q[6] = (p[6] * 2^(10–6)) mod 9 = (7 * 2⁴) mod 9 = 4

q[7] = 9

q[8] = (p[8] * 2^(10–8)) mod 9 = (6 * 2²) mod 9 = 6

q[9] = (p[9] * 2^(10–9)) mod 9 = (6 * 2¹) mod 9 = 3

i = 1..9  >>    Σ q[i] = 9 + 9 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 6 + 3 = 50

c1 = (10 — (Σ q[i] mod 10)) mod 10 = (10–50 mod 10) mod 10

c1 = (10–0) mod 10 = 0

So it would be >> 0182736450

---

Here is my code.

```
boolean isTurkishVID(String idnum) { 
    d=idnum;
    int v1 = 0;
    int v2 = 0;
    int v3 = 0;
    int v4 = 0;
    int v5 = 0;
    int v6 = 0;
    int v7 = 0;
    int v8 = 0;
    int v9 = 0;
    int v11 = 0;
    int v22 = 0;
    int v33 = 0;
    int v44 = 0;
    int v55 = 0;
    int v66 = 0;
    int v77 = 0;
    int v88 = 0;
    int v99 = 0;
    int v_last_digit = 0;
    int total = 0;


    if (d.size()==10) {

        v1 =  (d[0].toInteger() + 9) % 10;
        v2 =  (d[1].toInteger() + 8) % 10;
        v3 =  (d[2].toInteger() + 7) % 10;
        v4 =  (d[3].toInteger() + 6) % 10;
        v5 =  (d[4].toInteger() + 5) % 10;
        v6 =  (d[5].toInteger() + 4) % 10;
        v7 =  (d[6].toInteger() + 3) % 10;
        v8 =  (d[7].toInteger() + 2) % 10;
        v9 =  (d[8].toInteger() + 1) % 10;



        v11 = (v1 * 512) % 9;
        v22 = (v2 * 256) % 9;
        v33 = (v3 * 128) % 9;
        v44 = (v4 * 64) % 9;
        v55 = (v5 * 32) % 9;
        v66 = (v6 * 16) % 9;
        v77 = (v7 * 8) % 9;
        v88 = (v8 * 4) % 9;
        v99 = (v9 * 2) % 9;

        if (v1 != 0 && v11 == 0) v11 = 9;
        if (v2 != 0 && v22 == 0) v22 = 9;
        if (v3 != 0 && v33 == 0) v33 = 9;
        if (v4 != 0 && v44 == 0) v44 = 9;
        if (v5 != 0 && v55 == 0) v55 = 9;
        if (v6 != 0 && v66 == 0) v66 = 9;
        if (v7 != 0 && v77 == 0) v77 = 9;
        if (v8 != 0 && v88 == 0) v88 = 9;
        if (v9 != 0 && v99 == 0) v99 = 9;

        total = v11 + v22 + v33 + v44 + v55 + v66 + v77 + v88 + v99;


        if (total % 10 == 0) total = 0;
        else total = (10 - (total % 10));

        if (total == v_last_digit) {    
            return true;
        } else return false;

    } else return false;

}
```

It returns error when I use it like

```
isTurkishVI("1234567891");
```

Returns;

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript20.isTurkishVI() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1234567891]
  Possible solutions: isTurkishVID(java.lang.String)
  at ConsoleScript20.run(ConsoleScript20:74)
```

Comment: ehh u sure its not 11 digits? wikipedia suggests otherwise. Got a source for this?

Comment: method declared with name `isTurkishVID` and you are calling method with name `isTurkishVI` (without last `D`). and error message explains you this....

Comment: thnx actually it was a typo.. It work.. just info, Individual people turkish identiy number used as tax number as well, it has a separate algorithm.. This one for tax nımber belong companies etc.. It works.. Cheers..